# Proving differentiability of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm confused as to the dynamics of a proof that demonstrates that a function of two variables is differentiable.

I understand that to demonstrtate that ate a function is differentiable there must exist a linear map.

But I am not sure how to use that to prove that a function such as f(x,y) = $x^2+y^2$ is differentiable at (1,1).

Answer (score 1):

For differentiability at $(1, 1)$, the candidate for the linear map is
$$
A = \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg\rvert_{(1,1)}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg\rvert_{(1,1)}\right] = \left[2, 2\right].
$$

Now,
$$
f(1 + h, 1 + k) - f(1, 1) - A(h, k) = (1 + h)^2 + (1 + k)^2 - 2 - 2h - 2k = h^2 + k^2,
$$
thus
$$
\frac{f(1 + h, 1 + k) - f(1, 1) - A(h, k)}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} = \sqrt{h^2 + k^2} \rightarrow 0
$$
as $(h, k) \rightarrow (0, 0)$. Clearly $f$ is differentiable at $(1, 1)$.

---

Admittedly, this looks a bit like cheating. But it is really not, we are just using quite a few theorems...

1. A necessary condition for total derivative to exist is existence of all partial derivatives.
2. If total derivative does exist, all directional derivatives take the form
   $$f'(x;v) = Df(x)v,$$
   where $Df(x) = \left[\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)\right]_{i,j}$ is the Jacobian.
3. This, along with uniqueness of derivative, implies if total derivative exists, the linear map in definition of differentiability must be the Jacobian.

This gives a strategy for "guessing" what the linear map should be. You then verify that the map works.